# Adding CMK(Customer Managed Key) failing for empty Azure data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Adding Customer managed key  to brand new Data factory failing with below error message. Same error when i tried from Azure Portal or REST API (PUT https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/#####/resourceGroups/####/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/ )

I just created Data factory and it is empty. Following below link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/enable-customer-managed-key

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "AddCMKToExistingFactoriesWithEntities",
    "message": "Update factory failed. You cannot add CMK settings for factories with existing entities",
    "target": null,
    "details": null
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can I suggest you to please try and create a new test ADF and select the Enable encryption using CMK ? It should work that way .

[image]

Comment: I tried this option. When it is enabled it expects to provide user managed identity for keys in Keyvault. And when i provide user managed identity which has access to keyvault, it does not create identity for ADF itself (System assigned identity) which causes problem for me as i need System assigned identity for ADF

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft resolved this issue last week. Able to add CMK keys to new data factories with no entities.

Comment: Can I know what was the fix ?

Comment: Wer u able to add CMK with system assigned identity ?

Comment: Yes i was able to add CMK in data factory portal -> "manage" section

Answer (score 0):

I also encounter this issue, and nobody gives me a satisfactory answer in the [community](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/965053/adf-you-cannot-add-cmk-settings-for-factories-with.html?childToView=967953#comment-967953).

After a while, I found I shouldn't believe Azure UI in some situations. Especially for some unimportant features.

1. Create ADF by Azure CLI **(THIS IS IMPORTANT!!!)**

```bash
az datafactory create --location "Japan East" \
--name "ADF-CMK" \
--resource-group "<YOUR GROUP>"
```

2. Copy the identity object ID of ADF

[image]

3. Create an access policy

[image]

[image]

4. input your CMK URL to your ADF

[image]

---

See also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-service-identity#retrieve-managed-identity